# How to change Method type of API in apollo-angular

Tags: angular, graphql, angular7, apollo-angular

I am using Apollo angular client to call API in angular my some API's are  POST type and some are GET type and I want to change API method type as per API(GET or POST) I am new with this so please help me.
my code :

```
export class AppModule {

  constructor(
    apollo: Apollo,
    private httpLink: HttpLink
  ) {
    const auth = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
      const token = sessionStorage.getItem('token');
      if (!token) {
        return {};
      } else {
        return {
          headers: headers.append('Authorization', token)
        };
      }
    });
    const http = this.httpLink.create({ uri: '/api/graph', method: 'GET' });
    apollo.create({
      link: auth.concat(http),
      cache: new InMemoryCache()
    });
  }

}
```

1. Api method(GET Type):

   ```
   constructor(private router: Router,
       private apollo: Apollo,
       private appService: AppService) {
     }

     login() {
       this.apollo.query({query: MyQuery })
         .subscribe((data) => {
           if (data['data']) {
              console.log(err);
           }
         },
           err => {
             console.log(err);
           });
     }
   ```
2. API Method(POST Type) code:

   this.apollo.query(
         {
           query: MyQuery })
         .subscribe((data) => {
           console.log(data);
         },
           err => {
             console.log(err);
           });

I'm unable to call method 2(POST Type Method) because instance created as GET type and I want to change it as per my API method type

Please help me with this..

Answer (score 0):

You want to make a Graphql query using get?
Or only want to make a get request? in that case, you should use the httpclientmodule